# Displaying a composition & dependency relationship in class diagrams using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, class-diagram

I am trying to display a composition and dependency relationship in a class diagram using VS 2008, but there are no diagrams associated with the above mentioned relationship. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate supports composition, dependency, and many other relationships on UML class diagrams:

**UML Class Diagrams: Reference**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409437%28VS.100%29.aspx

[image: UML class diagram]

> **5**: **Association**: A relationship between the members of two classifiers.
>
> **5a**: **Aggregation**: An association representing a shared ownership relationship. The
> **Aggregation** property of the owner role is set to **Shared**.
>
> **5b**: **Composition**: An association representing a whole-part relationship. The **Aggregation**
> property of the owner role is set to **Composite**.
>
> **9**: **Generalization**: The specific classifier inherits part of its definition from the general
> classifier. The general classifier is at the arrow end of the connector. Attributes, associations, and
> operations are inherited by the specific classifier. Use the **Inheritance** tool to create a
> generalization between two classifiers.

[image]

> **13**: **Import**: A relationship between packages, indicating that one
> package includes all the definitions of another.
>
> **14**: **Dependency**: The definition or implementation of the dependent classifier might change if
> the classifier at the arrowhead end is changed.

[image]

> **15**: **Realization**: The class implements the operations and attributes defined by the interface.
> Use the **Inheritance** tool to create a realization between a class and an interface.
>
> **16**: **Realization**: An alternative presentation of the same relationship. The label on the
> lollipop symbol identifies the interface.

**UML Class Diagrams: Guidelines**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409416%28VS.100%29.aspx

> **Properties of an Association**
>
> **Aggregation**: This appears as a diamond shape at one end of the connector. You can use it to
> indicate that instances at the aggregating role own or contain instances of the other.
>
> **Is Navigable**: If true for only one role, an arrow appears in the navigable direction. You can use
> this to indicate navigability of links and database relations in the software.

> **Generalization**: Generalization means that the specializing or derived type inherits attributes,
> operations, and associations of the general or base type. The general type appears at the arrowhead
> end of the relationship.
>
> **Realization**: Realization means that a class implements the attributes and operations specified by
> the interface. The interface is at the arrow end of the connector.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: how can I change the realization presentation from 16 to 15?

Comment: Can you right-click the relationship and change it back to an interface?

Comment: if you right click on the lollipop symbol there are only to options: "Collapse" or "Properties", and none of them enables the presentation described in 15.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered yourself, the Class Diagram in VS2008 does not provide all of the functionality of a UML Class Diagram. A new "UML Class Diagram" has been introduced in Visual Studio 2010 to address this.