# Visual Studio UML Class Diagram does not show Generic Constraint

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, uml

I have a  InvestmentReturnCalculator abstract class in C# using .Net 4.0. A generic `InvestmentReturnCalculator<T>` class extends this class with a constraint `where T : IBusiness`

The class diagram generated in `Visual Studio 2012` is as given below. It does not show the `constraint`. This constraint is the most important part of the design which is missing.

What is the solution/workaround to display the `constraint` in the UML class diagram?

Note: I have referred [UML Class Diagrams: Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409416.aspx); but this does not address this issue.

[image]

**Code**

```
public abstract class InvestmentReturnCalculator
{
    public double ProfitElement { get; set; }
    public abstract double GetInvestmentProfit();

    public double CalculateBaseProfit()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

public abstract class InvestmentReturnCalculator<T> : InvestmentReturnCalculator where T : IBusiness
{
    public T Business { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264232/can-u-tell-me-how-to-display-a-composition-dependency-relationship-in-class-di

Answer (score 1):

A citation from your reference:

> Set the name property to a parameter name for your template type, for
>   example, Key.
>
> Set Parameter Kind. The default is Class.
>
> If you want the parameter to accept only derived classes of a
>   particular base class, set Constrained Value to the base class that
>   you want.

Where is the problem?

BTW, try not to mix this Constrained Value with the normal constraint (set as a note) and don't name it so.

Comment: The class diagram I created from existing code. Though the code has constraint, that is not reflected in the diagram. What additional steps do I need to take to reflect it?

Comment: All reverse engineering has only limited functionality, even on specialized modelling SW, let alone VS. So, try to set by hand what is in the citation. At least, I hope, that VS can uphold the diagrams up to the current state of application.

Comment: Haven't you noticed, that the very class is shown in correctly - T should appear in the small rectangle in the SE corner of the class rectangle, not in <>

Comment: Check the properties of the class. Are THEY correct? So you could divide error in drawing from error in code reading.